# What's this automotive connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to identify this connector. It's the connector for the fuel pressure sensor on my '02 Renault Laguna II. The contacts are intermittent and in need of replacing, but I can't find this connector anywhere. I've found some similar ones from TE Connectivity, but nothing that matches it exactly and would mate with the sensor.

The top features a logo, something like "Sigma", as well as ">PBT<" which simply identifies the type of plastic. The outside of the black plastic shroud is about 18 mm wide - I could take some more exact measurements later, if required.

Can anybody identify this model of connector or its manufacturer?

[image: side view]
[image: bottom view]
[image: front view]
[image: top logo]

Comment: People on the automotive SE might know more

Comment: @PlasmaHH good one. I saw quite a few similar connector identification questions here, so I thought I'd give EE a go first.

Comment: Try an Auto Salvage Yard, it might be a custom.

Comment: @Mels: You should always try where there is the highest possibility of someone lurking around who has seen them

Comment: Looks like it's a Tyco 1-2834074-3 but I'm not sure (writing from my smartphone). Go to TE.com and search "waterproof". I think you can find a matching one.

Comment: Thanks, but that part doesn't look like it matches. I have scanned through TE's site but can't find this exact connector. It may well be a custom job after all.

Answer (score 2):

I chased the Molex part ([33471-0301](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/33471-0301/WM4689-ND/1756770?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla1756770&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&gclid=Cj0KEQiAvNrBBRDe3IOwzLn6_O4BEiQAmbK-DhYoCs7exhqZqQwBu2lkl-9B8lNGvoNJjinLkjj5N8QaAvvU8P8HAQ)) suggested by @NateGreco to Molex's website, but following the data sheet link from the page Nate linked to on Digikey's site. There I found the set of [this PDF of the engineering drawings for the connector](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/334710301_sd.pdf) that are linked below. The drawings should enable you to determine pretty conclusively if this is the right connector. You may also be able to find numbers on the connector that will help verify whether or not it is right.

[image: engineering drawings of Molex 33471-0301]

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's a molex-style connector, as most automotive connectors are.  Similar to [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/33471-0301/WM4689-ND/1756770?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla1756770&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&gclid=Cj0KEQiAvNrBBRDe3IOwzLn6_O4BEiQAmbK-DhYoCs7exhqZqQwBu2lkl-9B8lNGvoNJjinLkjj5N8QaAvvU8P8HAQ)?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Delphi Metri-Pack connector. http://www.terminalsandconnectors.com/Products/Product/12059595

Answer (score -1):

This is an former FCI connector, since FCI is no more it's a Delphi connector now.